# Flutter Send Notification to Smart Watch (WearOs, Apple Watch)

Tags: flutter, wear-os, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication, android-wear-notification

I want to ask if you had any Idea how to send notification to  Smart watch (WearOs/Apple Watch) when the flutter app also receive notification from FCM

or if it possible to send local notification to Smart Watch